# Здравствуйте,проблема с библиотекой Tkinter.Почему окно 'warning_port_baud' открывается в окне 'win',если я установил его открытие только по условию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui, arduino

[Ссылка на проект](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/qti78YxjNqm81Q)

*my.py* - нужный файл.

Необходимо залить на ардуино код \Arduino\prototype.ino , предварительно выбрав бодрейт (строка 407)

Код целиком:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports
from tkinter import *
from Arduino import Arduino
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
import time

resx_win = str(int((GetSystemMetrics(0)/2)-(800/2)-9))          #
resy_win = str(int((GetSystemMetrics(1)/2)-(500/2)-35))         #
resx_head = str(int((GetSystemMetrics(0)/2) - (800/2)-9))       # Переменные для расположения окон посередине экрана
resy_head = str(int((GetSystemMetrics(1)/2) - (500/2)-35))      #
warningx_head = str(int((GetSystemMetrics(0)/2)-(300/2)-9))     #
warningy_head = str(int((GetSystemMetrics(1)/2) - (200/2)-35))  #

ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()  #
for port, desc, hwid in sorted(ports):      # Инициализация портов(разделение строки
    port                                    # состоящей из нескольких портов ещё не делал)
                                            # <Работает в тестовом режиме>


head = Tk()

head.geometry('800x500+'+resx_head+'+'+resy_head)
head.title('Лаунчер')
head.resizable(width=False, height=False)
head.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0.95)


def warning_port_baud_def():
    warning_port_baud = Tk()
    warning_port_baud.geometry('300x200+' + warningx_head + '+' + warningy_head)
    warning_port_baud.title('Ошибка')
    warning_canvas = Canvas(warning_port_baud, width=300, height=200)
    warning_canvas.pack()
    warning_port_baud_frame = Frame(warning_port_baud)
    warning_port_baud_frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

    warning_port_baud_label = Label(warning_port_baud_frame,text='Введите \nнеобходимые\n значения '    #
                                                '\nдля порта \nи скорости', font= ("message-box",16))   #
    warning_port_baud_label.place(x=120, y=20, width=180, height=150)                                   # Окно,вылезающее при
    global warning_image                                                                                # некорректном вводе
    warning_image = PhotoImage(file='y_warning.png', master=warning_port_baud_frame)                    # порта или бодрейта
    warning_ico = Label(warning_port_baud_frame, image=warning_image)                                   # Ну и картинка для
    warning_ico.place(x=15, y=43)                                                                       # этого окна
def WinSon():

    port_ch = (var_p.get())         #
    if port_ch == PortList[0]:      # Если в меню не выбран порт,
        port_ch = entry_p.get()     # читает поле ввода
        print(port_ch)              #

    baudrate = (var_bd.get())       #
    if baudrate == BaudList[0]:     # То же самое,
        baudrate = entry_bd.get()   # только уже с бодрейтом
        print(baudrate)             #

    if len(port_ch) or len(baudrate) == 0:  #
        print(len(port_ch))                 # Проверка на длину введённых данных
        print(len(baudrate))                # <Потом добавлю поиск подстроки 'COM'>
        warning_port_baud_def()             #

    board = Arduino(baudrate, port= port_ch)    # Инициализация ардуинки и её порта и скорости
    board.pinMode(13, "OUTPUT")                 # Добавил,пока,просто так
    head.withdraw()
    win = Toplevel()
    win.geometry('800x500+' + resx_win + '+' + resy_win)
    win.title('Набор')

    win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: head.destroy())    # Закрывает окно head,при открытии этого

    canvas2 = Canvas(win,width = 800,height = 500)
    canvas2.pack()
    frame_lobby = Frame(win)
    frame_lobby.place(relwidth = 1,relheight = 1)

    win.mainloop()


canvas = Canvas(head,width = 800,height = 500)
canvas.pack()
frame = Frame(head)
frame.place(relwidth = 1,relheight = 1)


bg = PhotoImage(file = 'bg_800x500.png')    #
wallpaper = Label(frame,image = bg)         # Пикча для BG
wallpaper.pack()                            #


t_p = Label(frame, text='ПОРТ/выбери или напиши', bg='#A52A2A',font = 20)   #
t_p.place(x=20, y = 220, width = 370, height = 60)                          #
PortList = ['Выберите порт', port]                                          #
var_p = StringVar(frame)                                                    # Меню для порта
var_p.set(PortList[0])                                                      #
opt_p = OptionMenu(frame, var_p, *PortList)                                 #
opt_p.place(x=20, y=280, width=185, height=30)                              #

entry_p = Entry(frame,font = 15)                                            # Поле ввода для порта
entry_p.place(x = 205,y = 280,width = 185,height = 30)                      #


t_bd = Label(frame,text = 'БОДРЕЙТ указанный в \nскетче ардуино/выбери или напиши', #
    bg = '#A52A2A',font = 20)                                                       #
t_bd.place(x = 410,y = 220,width = 370,height = 60)                                 #
BaudList = ['Выберите скорость',9600,19200,38400,57600,115200]                      # Меню для бодрейта
var_bd = StringVar(frame)                                                           #
var_bd.set(BaudList[0])                                                             #
opt_bd = OptionMenu(frame, var_bd, *BaudList)                                       #
opt_bd.place(x = 410,y = 280,width = 185,height = 30)                               #

entry_bd = Entry(frame, font=15,bd = 3)                                             # Поле ввода для бодрейта
entry_bd.place(x=595, y=280, width=185, height=30)                                  #


further = PhotoImage(file = 'далее.png')                                            #
small_further = further.subsample(15, 15)                                           # Кнопка и картинка
further_Button = Button(frame,text = 'Далее',image = small_further,                 # выполняет команду
    compound = LEFT,font = ("lucida console", 16),bd = 5,command = WinSon)          # WinSon
further_Button.place(x = 350,y = 370,width = 130,height = 50)                       #


head.mainloop()
```

**Само условие**

```
    if len(port_ch) or len(baudrate) == 0:  #
        print(len(port_ch))                 # Проверка на длину введённых данных
        print(len(baudrate))                # <Потом добавлю поиск подстроки 'COM'>
        warning_port_baud_def()             #
```

Comment: а где это условие ?

Comment: @Интик ,дополнил вопрос

Comment: if len(port_ch)  тру когда не 0 это так задумано или вы планировали if len(port_ch) ==0 or len(baudrate) == 0 опишите словами что в условии должно произойти.

Comment: @Интик ,if len(port_ch) это проверка на длину символов выбранного порта,если порт не выбрать,вылезет ошибка.Так же и с бодрейтом(стоит or,то есть если порт или бодрейт не выбран,вылазит ошибка).Но условие не законченное,как и говорил в комментариях к коду,потом добавлю поиск на наличие "COM"
Но насколько я понял ошибка в построении условия,нужно было сделать так
if len(port_ch) == 0 or len(baudrate) == 0: ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была в построении условия,ниже **неправильный вариант**

```
if len(port_ch) or len(baudrate) == 0:  #
    print(len(port_ch))                 # Проверка на длину введённых данных
    print(len(baudrate))                # <Потом добавлю поиск подстроки 'COM'>
    warning_port_baud_def()             #
```

А это уже **рабочий(правильный)**

```
if len(port_ch) == 0 or len(baudrate) == 0:  #
    print(len(port_ch))                 # Проверка на длину введённых данных
    print(len(baudrate))                # <Потом добавлю поиск подстроки 'COM'>
    warning_port_baud_def()             #
```

Большое спасибо [***Интику***](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1260751/%d0%97%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-tkinter-%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be-warning-port-baud-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80/1262869#comment2219546_1260751) за помощь в обнаружении ошибки